# R bnlearn Grow-Shrink structure learning

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

The Nagarajan et al. book (Bayesian Networks in R, O'Reilly 2013, p. 35) says that when I take the marks dataset of the R bnlearn package and ask to learn structure using the grow-shrink implementation by writing

```
library(bnlearn)
data(marks)
bn.gs = gs(marks)
```

When I apply

```
bn.gs = gs(marks)
```

bn.gs or even bn.hc, it says that:

> "Error in matrix(c(x$d, x$pi, x$sigma, x$rho), ncol = 1) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'"

It seems it has problem with my data type, which is exactly the same as book. What can I do?

Comment: I cant reproduce this. Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please. Also does the problem persist on a new R session?

Comment: I fail to reproduce this (3.3.1, Win7). Are you sure those three lines are the ones you're using at the start of a new session, and the error comes after running the last one?

Comment: @user20650
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Comment: @JonathanCarroll, yes I exactly use: rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

>library(bnlearn)
> data(marks)
>bn.gs = gs(marks)
>print(bn.gs)

& I added the sessionInfo() as well

Comment: @GulfChanter and which line causes the error?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll the last one >bn.gs=gs(marks)
It shows:
Biased Net Model

Parameters:

Error in matrix(c(x$d, x$pi, x$sigma, x$rho), ncol = 1) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Comment: `gs(mark)` or `gs(marks)`?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll
Even when I write
dag <- empty.graph(nodes = c("A", "S", "E", "O", "R", "T"))
print(dag)
It shows that error

Comment: If you type `?bnlearn` - what version/date is mentioned in the help file?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll
Version:  4.0
Date:  2016-05-12
License:  GPLv2 or later

Comment: @GulfChanter; can you edit your question with the full output of `sessionInfo()` please , including all packages. Have you tried reinstalling `bnlearn`?. Before running the model search, what does `head(marks)` show?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this, but I'm hoping we can figure out what's happening because you appear to be on the same setup as I am. I'm posting this as an answer so that code shows up, but I'll modify this to the answer once we get there.

Please try:

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/reprex")
library(reprex)
```

copy this code to your clipboard (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

```
library(bnlearn)
data(marks)
bn.gs = gs(marks)
bn.gs
```

then type

```
reprex(venue = "so")
```

and paste the output. You should get something like the following if it works (and should fail if it's not a reproducible error)

```r
library(bnlearn)
data(marks)
bn.gs = gs(marks)
bn.gs
#> 
#>   Bayesian network learned via Constraint-based methods
#> 
#>   model:
#>     [undirected graph]
#>   nodes:                                 5 
#>   arcs:                                  6 
#>     undirected arcs:                     6 
#>     directed arcs:                       0 
#>   average markov blanket size:           2.40 
#>   average neighbourhood size:            2.40 
#>   average branching factor:              0.00 
#> 
#>   learning algorithm:                    Grow-Shrink 
#>   conditional independence test:         Pearson's Correlation 
#>   alpha threshold:                       0.05 
#>   tests used in the learning procedure:  44 
#>   optimized:                             TRUE
```